# Using a chart as a background spanning on a few cards

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Assuming I have these cards:

[image]

([Link to implementation in tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WNQghMQJbT))

And assuming I have this chart ([Example chart](https://echarts.apache.org/next/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-stack-gradient))

[image]

How can I achieve the effect of using that chart as a background for my cards?

Sort of like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split your chart into 3 different images. One for each of the cards. Then use the CSS `background` property to makes them the background for the cards.

Comment: Yeah but the problem with that is that I don't need the chart static, but rather dynamic - in other words, preserve the chart capability of changing.

Comment: As an idea you could play with z-index. Add one big div, behind your cards, contaning them, and on top that div paint your graph. Also, change all your card's opacity and z-index as needed. Just an idea, as I can't test it.